# MySql get row if id is in sequence

Tags: php, mysql

We require to get row if `product_id` is in sequence.

**Table** (product)

```
product_id    name

    1         Parle
    2         Coconut
    3         Pizza
    4         Colgate
    5         Ice Cream
    6         Nuts
    8         Britania
    9         Pepsi
```

**Require Output**

```
product_id    name

    1         Parle
    2         Coconut
    3         Pizza
    4         Colgate
    5         Ice Cream
    6         Nuts
```

> `product_id - 8 and 9` not getting because it is not in sequence.

**My Try**

```
select distinct t1.*, t1.product_id, (select GROUP_CONCAT(t2.product_id) from product as t2) as p_id
from product t1
having FIND_IN_SET(t1.product_id+1, p_id)
```

**Output**

```
product_id    name

    1         Parle
    2         Coconut
    3         Pizza
    4         Colgate
    5         Ice Cream
```

> In this try i am not getting `product_id - 6` row.
>
> Note : I want `MySql` query not in `PHP`.

Thank You !

Comment: You are attaching a grouping property to your product ID that would be better off in a separate column.

Comment: From where the sequence will start ?

Comment: Only 1 to 6 row nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way i can think of is to user user defined variable to get the rank of row and then calculate the difference of product id and rank and select only those rows where difference = 0

```
select *
from(
  select f.*,@row:= @row + 1 rank,
  product_id - @row as diff
  from product f,
  (select @row:= 0) t
  order by product_id
) t1
where diff = 0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8be/7)

Or if you want to pick the least sequence no. automatically you can write it as

```
select *
 from(
  select f.*,@row:= @row + 1 rank,
  product_id - @row as diff
  from product f,
  (select @row:= (select min(product_id)  from product_sale_flag) a) t
  order by product_id
) t1
where diff = -1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8be/13)

> **Explanation**
>   [First query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8be/23) assign's minimum value of `product_id` to variable `@row`,then it assigns a [rank](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8be/24) to each row ordered by `product_id` in ascending order, once rank is assigned for every row then it calculates the [difference between the original value of `product_id`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8be/26) and [lastly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c8be/25) using the resultant difference it checks where difference is 0 get those rows because they follow the sequence. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Thank you. it is working very well. But i can't understand please explain if you want.